# Docker image load failed on mac, error is 'invalid argument'

Tags: macos, docker

When I execute 'docker load file', something was wrong:

XXXdeMacBook-Pro:~ wuxinming$ sudo docker load -i crm_mysql-0.1.tar

```
invalid argument
```

XXXdeMacBook-Pro:~ wuxinming$ docker version

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.0-rc2
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   906eacd
 Built:        Fri Jun 17 20:35:33 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
 Experimental: true

Server:
 Version:      1.12.0-rc2
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   a7119de
 Built:        Fri Jun 17 22:09:20 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

The command works well on Windows and Linux, but not Mac.

Comment: Is that the only error message you are getting? Can you post your whole error message?

Comment: That is the only one.

Comment: Could you try it with the debug flag in order to get perhaps some more information, i.e. sudo docker -D load -i crm_mysql-0.1.tar

Comment: It's OK when I restart my mac......

Comment: if tar is corrupted the also that issue comes.Check your tar might be become 0 kb size.