# Error when loading a docker imager

Tags: image, docker

I have a compressed docker image (call it `image.tar.gz`) which I'm trying to load with the following command:

```
$ docker load -i image.tar.gz
```

I get an "invalid argument" error. I tested docker (1.12.3) after the installation and it worked fine. I also restarted my mac as suggested here ([Docker image load failed on mac, error is 'invalid argument'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38076830/docker-image-load-failed-on-mac-error-is-invalid-argument)) but it did not change anything. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/), what you have used seemed to be correct.  That is strange.

May be you can use below command to see if that goes well:

```
$ docker load < imageName.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually think the image file was corrupted / incomplete, which is the reason behind the error message.